# How are the "repos" yaml files generated?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "building ROS2 from source" instructions at https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html use a "repos" file in yaml format: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/foxy/ros2.repos.

How is this file generated?

In ROS1, this kind of file was generated with the `rosinstall_generator` tool (http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source#noetic.2FInstallation.2FSource.Create_a_catkin_Workspace). Is there something similar for ROS2?

I am asking because I would like to build ROS2 from source with fewer irrelevant packages (e.g. without any of `ros-visualization` or without `ros2/rviz`). The only workarounds to prevent building irrelevant packages are 1) removing packages from the repos file manually, 2) deleting source folders after the complete checkout, or 3) by placing `COLCON_IGNORE` files.

But there surely must be a better way by just specifying the packages of interest and generating the "repos" file programmatically.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396456/how-are-the-%22repos%22-yaml-files-generated?/) by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2022-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The "building ROS2 from source" instructions [..] use a "repos" file in [yaml format](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/foxy/ros2.repos). [..] How are the "repos" yaml files generated?

IIRC, that specific file is not generated by any tool. It's a manually managed file which was historically only used for CI purposes and for building ROS 2 from source by core developers. At some point it got repurposed to also be used by 'regular users' to build ROS 2 on their own machines.

That file does not contain "everything ROS 2", and for good reason: nightly builds of ROS 2 based on the contents of that file already sometimes time-out -- or at the very least take a (very) long time, as *everything* in there is built as part of a single build.

There have been quite a few PRs which wanted to add more packages to that file (and files similar to it) simply because such builds do not scale.

[This comment](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/issues/1470#issuecomment-834340732) by @clalancette highlights the difference between `repos.yaml` and whatever a tool like `rosinstall_generator` will generate:

> Before we make changes here, I think it is worthwhile to define the target audience of the build-from-source instructions.
>
> If the target audience is "people who can't use the binary packages, but just want to use ROS 2", then I agree that switching to `rosinstall_generator` is better. It will get them something closer to what the Debian packages are providing.
>
> But if the target audience is "people who want to work on the core of ROS 2", the situation is murkier to me. The current instructions more-or-less follow how the CI jobs work (at least on Linux and macOS; Windows is now totally different). That means that if a user checks things out in that way, and runs the appropriate tests, there is a good chance that things will work on the CI job when they open a PR. If we switch to `rosinstall_generator` for the instructions, then that is further away from what CI does.
>
> There is a way to resolve this discrepancy, which is to make the CI jobs use `rosinstall_generator`. That is one of the long-term goals I would like to get done for ROS 2, so maybe it is worthwhile addressing that first.

As you already noticed, `rosinstall_generator` will create an even larger `.repos` file for you. That's the *discrepancy* Chris refers to.

> In ROS1, this kind of file was generated with the `rosinstall_generator` tool (http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source#noetic.2FInstallation.2FSource.Create_a_catkin_Workspace). Is there something similar for ROS2?

You can still use `rosinstall_generator`.

ROS 2 packages are still released using Bloom, which still pushes commits to `ros/rosdistro`. That information is the same as used by `rosinstall_generator` with ROS 1.

`.repos` files can be generated by [dirk-thomas/vcstool](https://github.com/dirk-thomas/vcstool), but `vcs` also supports the `.rosinstall` format. If you really want to have `.repos` files, append `--format=repos` to your `rosinstall_generator` command line.

A few older/related Q&As: #q378063, #q299473, #q339570, #q379624 (with linked Discourse discussion: [Core, base and desktop releases](https://discourse.ros.org/t/core-base-and-desktop-releases/20267)), #q319587 and #q325245.

> The only workarounds to prevent building irrelevant packages are 1) removing packages from the repos file manually, 2) deleting source folders after the complete checkout, or 3) by placing `COLCON_IGNORE` files.

Colcon actually supports quite extensive ways to select and/or ignore (sets of) packages, similar to how `catkin_tools` allowed you to build only subsets of a workspace (even as part of a *profile*). That's not the same as never checking out those sources, but since you suggested a few work-arounds which required changes to the artefacts in your workspace, I wanted to mention it.

See [Colcon documentation: Package selection arguments](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/package-selection-arguments.html):

> ```
> --packages-up-to [PKG_NAME [PKG_NAME …]]
> ```

```
  Select the packages with the passed names as well as their recursive dependencies.
```

> ```
> --packages-up-to-regex [PATTERN [PATTERN …]]
> ```

```
  Select the packages that match any of the passed patterns as well as their recursive dependencies.
```

> ```
> --packages-above [PKG_NAME [PKG_NAME …]]
> ```

```
  Select the packages with the passed names as well as packages which recursively depend on them.
```

> ```
> --packages-above-and-dependencies [PKG_NAME [PKG_NAME …]]
> ```

```
  Select the packages with the passed names, packages which recursively depend on them as well as their recursive dependencies.
```

> ```
> --packages-above-depth DEPTH [PKG_NAME …]
> ```

```
  Select the packages with the passed names as well as packages which recursively depend on them up to the given depth.
```

> ```
> --packages-select-by-dep [DEP_NAME [DEP_NAME …]]
> ```

```
  Select packages which (recursively) depend on the given packages.
```

> ```
> --packages-skip-by-dep [DEP_NAME [DEP_NAME …]]
> ```

```
  Skip packages which (recursively) depend on the given packages.
```

> ```
> --packages-skip-up-to [PKG_NAME [PKG_NAME …]]
> ```

```
  Skip the packages with the passed names as well as their recursive dependencies.
```

> ```
> --packages-select-build-failed
> ```

```
  Select packages which have failed to build previously. Packages which have been aborted previously are not included.
```

> ```
> --packages-skip-build-finished
> ```

```
  Skip packages which have finished to build previously.
```

> ```
> --packages-select-test-failures
> ```

```
  Select packages which had test failures previously.
```

> ```
> --packages-skip-test-passed
> ```

```
  Skip packages which had no test failures previously.
```

> ```
> --packages-select [PKG_NAME [PKG_NAME …]]
> ```

```
  Select the packages with the passed names.
```

> ```
> --packages-skip [PKG_NAME [PKG_NAME …]]
> ```

```
  Skip the packages with the passed names.
```

> ```
> --packages-select-regex [PATTERN [PATTERN …]]
> ```

```
  Select the packages where any of the patterns match the package name.
```

> ```
> --packages-skip-regex [PATTERN [PATTERN …]]
> ```

```
  Skip the packages where any of the patterns match the package name.
```

> ```
> --packages-start PKG_NAME
> ```

```
  Skip packages before the given package name in flat topological ordering. This option only makes sense when using the sequential executor.
```

> ```
> --packages-end PKG_NAME
> ```

```
  Skip packages after the given package name in flat topological ordering. This option only makes sense when using the sequential executor.
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) on 2022-02-20**:
Thanks. While this certainly can reduce the number of downloaded source packages, I am still having trouble somehow replicating the repo file. Generating a minimal installation via `rosinstall_generator ros_core --rosdistro galactic --deps --format=repos > base.repos` still adds more repos (166 via `cat base.repos | grep "type: git" | wc -l`) than what is found in the "official" `ros2.repos` (102). This file may be generated manually, but do you manage to include all the visualization packages without the `ros_core`? I also noticed that the git repos are different.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-02-21**:
I'm not sure I understand what you're asking when you say:

> This file may be generated manually, but do you manage to include all the visualization packages without the `ros_core`?

`ros_core` doesn't include any UI-based packages, and that's on purpose.

Or are you asking how to download the sources for all UI-based packages that are *not* in `ros_core`, but without also downloading `ros_core` packages?